# Running an ANOVA on a likert scale question

Tags: anova, likert

My participants heard two kinds of stories i.e. two conditions and rated two protagonists in each of these stories or conditions on a Likert scale of -5 to +5.
So I had two conditions, eight stories (four in each condition), and two protagonists in each of these stories i.e. the participants answered a total of 16 likert scale questions.
Now, I want to analyze this data with age (below 5 and above 5), condition (2) and the stories as my independent variables. The 16 questions will be my dependant variables. I could only think of ANOVA as the right way to do it. However, I am pretty new to statistics, can someone please help me do this the right way?

I will be grateful, thank you

Comment: Are you combining the results of the 16 questions into one value for each participant ?  Or do you intend to treat each question as a separate dependent variable ?  Or something else ?